# REST API - Javascript or PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, api, rest

With a REST API I can receive a response in XML or in JSON. This can be done using PHP or Javascript (using jQuery) for example.

I want to know the advantages and the disadvantages of the different languages. This is what I figured out so far:

- PHP seems easier than JavaScript when data needs to be used on the server side for later.
- JavaScript runs on the client side and does not make a load on the server when fetching data with external URLs

Comment: This question is highly subjective, so I won't answer and I will vote to close. That said, I'll just correct a couple of errors in the premise. With a REST API you can get **any** kind of data that the API supports, REST does not automatically mean XML/JSON (although the particular, unspecified, one you are using might be limited to those data formats). JavaScript is a general programming language, [it is not limited to the client](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_server-side_JavaScript_solutions).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Javascript call will not place a load on your server if the REST API is on an external domain (i.e. not yours). jQuery's ajax() call offers a work-around to allow you to GET data from external domains.

Use PHP if:

- You want to save the output from the API in your own database
- You want to call the API perdioically to get updates rather than have each user call it every time they view a page that uses it. If you have thousands of pageviews a day but the data from the API only changes once a month then this would save expensive calls.
- If you need to POST to the API. You can't do a POST to another domain using Javascript
- You want to do some heavy analysis on the data or you want to analysis data from multiple API calls over time

Use Javascript when:

- The API provides up-to-the-minute data that need to be queried on each page view
- You are using Ajax to update your webpages

Answer (score 3):

Disregarding any other server side language, when you create your own REST API, the most common way is using **PHP for backend** and **JavaScript for the client side**. But there is also the possibility to write JavaScript at the backend ([Learning Server-Side JavaScript with Node.js](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/learning-serverside-javascript-with-node-js/)).

> Javascripts run on the client side and does not make a load on the
>   server when fetching data with external URLs.

Thats only half the truth, if I understood your question right. If you need data from an external source, JavaScript will be prevented from doing so due to the **same origin policy**. But there are many possibilities to load data from some other origin like ajax proxy (using your backend as bridge) or JSONP.

Comment: No, and thats not what I ment. "Disregarding any other server side language...", I just focused on PHP and JavaScript.